# how to list table rows of a layer in a listbox?

Tags: arcmap, c#, arcgis-engine

I'm new in using c# and Arcengine .
 i would like to list table rows of a feature in a Listbox like select by attribute in ArcGIS
such that when i click a button, table rows list in a listbox . i use two combobox to select layers and fields . how can i write this code in C# using Arc engine? i don't know how do i write loop for this purpose. i only know i want to run the application in ArcGIS then i use Ihookhelper and Itable.

Comment: This is too broad a question to be answered here. I would suggest narrowing your question down to the ArcObjects side of it and learn how to create a UI on your own (try searching for Windows Forms or WPF tutorials assuming you are using one of those frameworks).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the legality of this (found it through a Google search) but here is a training manual (exercises) from the ESRI training course Introduction to Programming ArcObjects using the Microsoft .NET Framework: http://env1.kangwon.ac.kr/gis/manuals/engine/docs/introduction_to_programming_arcobjects_using_net_full.pdf

There is a lot of step by step walkthrough and code samples in there you may find useful.